# Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::comment does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, migration, lumen

I need a help about a easy question, when I use the following code

`DB::statement("ALTER TABLE` user `comment 'User comment'");`

this code work in my laravel migration.

But when I use same code laravel documentantion

`Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->comment('User comment'); });`

My output in the terminal is as follows

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::comment does not exist.

I tried

`Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->comment('User comment'); });`

I expected results is succesfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration table comments for MySQL and Postgres are released with laravel version 9.14: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-9-14-0

So, if you want to use this feature, you have to update your laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

I was using PHP 7 and the installation of Laravel contemplated version 8, after migrating to PHP 8 it was possible to install Laravel 9 in which the syntax worked

Answer (score -1):

You should define the column first before you use the `comment()`. Since the `comment` is a method from the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition::class` you cannot access it using the `$table` which is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::class` :

```
$table->string('name'); // Return type is ColumnDefinition class it means the you can access the comment() after the string(),

$table->string('name')->comment('Name of the user');
```

[Laravel - Column Modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-modifiers)